# How to use an image instead of a marker in an animated graph using Matplot.lib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, animation

I have been trying to use an image that moves in an animation instead of "ro" (red dots) or similar markers. [image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DTWQ.png), [image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8R6O.png), [image_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2eq9.png) So far I have a graph that has a little red dot moving over the dotted line. I want an image to be the one that moves through the dotted line instead of a red dot.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []

img = plt.imread("/Users/salomondabbah/Desktop/mar.jpg")
ax.imshow(img, extent=[0, 2 * np.pi, -1, 1])

xtrack = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 240)
ytrack = np.sin(xtrack)
ln, = plt.plot([], [], ***'ro'***, zorder=15)

ax.plot(xtrack, np.sin(xtrack), 'k', linewidth=25.0, zorder=5)
ax.plot(xtrack, ytrack, '--y',linewidth=2.0, zorder=10)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    ln.set_data(frame, np.sin(frame))
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance for any solutions provided to my issue!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what you are doing, but using `set_extent` with `imshow` instead of `set_data` with a line:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
xdata, ydata = [], []

xtrack = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 240)
ytrack = np.sin(xtrack)
img = plt.imread("car.png")
im = ax.imshow(img, zorder=10, aspect='auto')

ax.plot(xtrack, np.sin(xtrack), 'k', linewidth=25.0, zorder=5)
ax.plot(xtrack, ytrack, '--y',linewidth=2.0, zorder=10)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    l = frame - 0.5
    r = frame + 0.5
    b = np.sin(frame) - 0.2
    t = np.sin(frame) + 0.2
    im.set_extent([l,r,b,t])
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=False)
ani.save('ani.gif', writer='pillow')
```

[image]

The only finnicky thing is getting the desired size & aspect ratio of the graph and size & aspect ratio of the car.  The overall graph can be edited by using `figsize` when it is created as I have added.  But if you don't set the `aspect` parameter of the `imshow` to `auto`, it will override the figure size and shape, in order to make the image have correct dimensions (it seems).  So you may have to play around with the `0.5` and `0.2` values in the `update` to keep your image having approximately correct dimensions.